# Any idea why this "if else" isn't working properly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
 if (selectedSize = 60) {
    document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = x;
  } else if (selectedSize = "select") {
      document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = " Please choose a size!";
  }
    
  if (selectedSize = 50) {
      document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = y;
  } else if (selectedSize = "select") {
      document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = " Please choose a size!";
  }
```

When I run it, it ALWAYS goes down to the second if statement and says that it's true. No matter what I do... thoughts?

Comment: `=` should be `==` in the comparisons.

Comment: Why do you need to check for `selectedSize == "select"` twice?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan `===` probably won't work in this case, unless they change `60` and `50` to `"60"` and `"50"`

Comment: Okay, so when I do that, it breaks it. Nothing happens, there is no output at all...

Comment: Which did you use, `==` or `===`?

Comment: What is the actual value of `selectedSize`?

Comment: @Barmar Adding the quotations worked! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: More important, do you understand *why* you needed to add them?

Comment: @Barmar it is reading what selection is made from a dropdown and adjusting the price accordingly, but it's not automatic right now, so I have hardcoded the price in.

Comment: @Barmar Yes! I am just tired at the end of a long day, and missed it! :) Thank you!

Comment: I mean do you understand the difference between `==` and `===`, and why you need quotes when you use `===`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes! I appreciate the help in finding a VERY Noticeable typo that I missed.

Comment: The typo was `=`. Do you understand why when you changed it to `===` you also needed to add quotes? And why you wouldn't need them if you changed it to `==`?

Answer (score 2):

As the comments note, you've used the assignment (=) operator where you should be using == or strict equals ===. However, you should prefer a switch statement where you have multiple options, i.e.:

```
switch (selectedSize) {
  case 'select':
    document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = " Please choose a size!";
    break;
  case '50': 
    document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = y;
    break;
  case '60': 
    document.getElementById("outputCost").innerHTML = x;
    break;
}
```

Note, these are select values, which will be strings rather than numbers, so '50', not 50.

Comment: `50` and `60` should be strings, not numbers, since `switch` uses strict equality.

Comment: Yes - I just added an edit as I assume 50 and 60 probably are strings.

Comment: The actual value is presumably the value of a `<select>`, so it will be a string. Read the comments where he said he needed to quote the  numbers when using `===`.

Comment: aha - will edit.